# Can't update composer(ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04

I want to composer update but, it gives me error like this.

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpoffice/phpexcel 1.8.0 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpexcel[1.8.0].
    - phpoffice/phpexcel 1.8.0 requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension xml is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Here is my `composer.json`

```
"require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "1.8.0" 
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the extensions to run well Yii2 are not installed, you can correct it by reinstalling the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xmlrpc php7.0-xml
```

Answer (score 0):

install php extension`sudo apt-get install php-xmlrpc php-xml`